# Javascript Ajax to ASP.NET Controller class - array of array parameter

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I´m having difficulties matching Javascript Ajax to ASP.NET Controller type. All parameters comes fine, except for the MsgData that comes null when received by the Controller.

My Controller classes and code:

```
public class AjaxMessage
{
    public enum MsgStatusType : int { OK, NOK }

    public string MsgType { get; set; }
    public List<AjaxMessageItem> MsgData { get; set; }
    public MsgStatusType MsgStatus { get; set; }
    public string MsgStatusMsg { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
public class AjaxMessageItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public AjaxMessageItem()
    {
        Name = String.Empty;
        Value = String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Finally:

```
    public ActionResult Get(AjaxMessage ajaxMessage)
    {
           ... do some stuff...
    }
```

My Javascript call:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Get", "AjaxServer")';

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        'MsgType': 'MsgType1',
        'MsgData': { 'Name': 'customerId', 'Value': 'current' },
        'MsgStatus': 'OK',
        'MsgStatusMessage' : ''
    },
    success: function (data) {

        if (data.msgStatus != 'OK') {
            var errorMsg = 'Error reading data.' + data.msgStatusMessage;
            alert(errorMsg);
            return;
        }

          ... do some stuff...
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert('Error retrieving Ajax data.');
    }
});
```

At controller, I´m getting `MsgType`, `MsgStatus` and `MsgStatusMsg` fine whan looking for ajaxMessage variable, but `MsgData` is always `null` and shall be receiving the `customerId` data.

I need some help to solve that. Please help me to find out what´s missing... Thanks.

Comment: You do not seem to be passing your `MsgData` as an array. Don't know if it is just a typo perhaps but it should probably be: `'MsgData': [{ 'Name': 'customerId', 'Value': 'current' }],`.

Comment: I tried that. Then the null at MsgData turned to be [1], but the values are empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're sending an array, you will have to convert the object to JSON explicitly using `JSON.stringify`, wrap the MsgData in `[]` and set `contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8'`

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        'MsgType': 'MsgType1',
        'MsgData': [{ 'Name': 'customerId', 'Value': 'current' }],
        'MsgStatus': 'OK',
        'MsgStatusMessage' : ''
    }),
    success: function (data) {

        if (data.msgStatus != 'OK') {
            var errorMsg = 'Error reading data.' + data.msgStatusMessage;
            alert(errorMsg);
            return;
        }

          ... do some stuff...
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert('Error retrieving Ajax data.');
    }
});
```

Comment: Not exactly this code, but I used jagged string outside the ajax call and then called the JSON.stringfy. Working fine for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

your data is sent to server, but you cant get that correctly, you can check the `network` tab of your browser, or check data has been sent to server by something like this:

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.Form.ToString())
```

i think the easiest way is always `stringify` your data, and `deserializing` that to your poco object on server

Comment: Is there a place to put that in case the action method does not work (like if you have a wrong placement of variable names - in that case the controller action will not be called) ? thanks.